# Slider causing white space on right hand side

Tags: removing-whitespace

I'm developing a website and there is white space on the right hand side of the home page. I know it's something to do with the image slider as it only happens on the home page where the slider is.

See here: [Home Page](http://dev3.displaywizard.co.uk/)

The issue is most noticeable on iPhone's and but desktop browsers add a scroll bar. On browsers you will notice that when you hover over the slider the scroll bar disappears.

The slider has been customized so the images are background images so they can be centered on the page.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it now!

It was the `.flexslider:hover .flex-next` and `.flexslider:hover .flex-prev` that had some CSS applied to them: `left:-38px;` and `right:-38px;`